# ограничить поле действия html

Tags: javascript, html, css, webbrowser

имеется html который я вставляю в document динамически, к нему же имеется css.
вставлять тоже легко просто с помощью

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
```

проблема что может быть так что вставленный в определенный div html вылезит из за границ куда вставлен html из за css стилей. 
Можно ли как то создать искуственную границу будто этот div браузер.

Comment: прикрепите скриншоты и код стилей, а лучше ссылку на песочницу чтоб мы хоть как-то понимали в чем проблема

Comment: @MishaSaidov, скрин то на кой? Пример должен быть читабельным и редактируемым...

Comment: Покажи верстку....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. когда дочерний элемент шире/выше родителя

   достаточно родителю установить значение `overflow = 'scroll'`

   [MDN CSS/overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)
2. когда дочерний элемент имеет фиксированное положение

   необходимо использовать `iframes`

   [javascript.ru iframes](https://learn.javascript.ru/iframes)

---

пример

- серая рамка - родитель
- синяя рамка - шире/выше родителя
- красная рамка - имеет фиксированное положение

```js
let html = (template, ...substitutions) => String.raw(template, ...substitutions);
// --> Begin
var main;
(function (main) {
    function guidGenerator() {
        var S4 = function () {
            return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
        };
        // return (S4()+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+S4()+S4());
        return 'q' + S4() + S4();
    }
    main.guidGenerator = guidGenerator;
})(main || (main = {}));
(function (main) {
    function fixOverflow(el) {
        el.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    }
    main.fixOverflow = fixOverflow;
    function allowOverflow(el) {
        el.style.overflow = '';
    }
    main.allowOverflow = allowOverflow;
    function addButtons(el) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html `
            <input type="button" class="foos" data-id="fix" value="fixOverflow">
            <input type="button" class="foos" data-id="allow" value="allowOverflow">
        `);
        let foos = {
            fix(e) {
                fixOverflow(el);
            },
            allow(e) {
                allowOverflow(el);
            },
        };
        let arrOfFoos = Array.from(el.getElementsByClassName('foos'));
        arrOfFoos.forEach((el) => {
            el.onclick = foos[el.dataset.id];
        });
    }
    main.addButtons = addButtons;
})(main || (main = {}));
// --
(function (main) {
    function addConteiner(el, name = main.guidGenerator()) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html `
            <style>
                #${name} {
                    padding:0;
                    margin:20px;
                    width:400px;
                    height:152px;
                    border: solid 2px grey;
                }
            </style>
            <div id="${name}">${name}</div>
        `);
        return document.getElementById(name);
    }
    main.addConteiner = addConteiner;
})(main || (main = {}));
// --
(function (main) {
    function addBadElement(el, name = main.guidGenerator()) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html `
            <style>
                .${name} {
                    width: 2845px;
                    height:745px;
                    border: solid 2px blue;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="${name}">${name}</div>
        `);
    }
    main.addBadElement = addBadElement;
})(main || (main = {}));
// --
(function (main) {
    function addBad2Element(el, name = main.guidGenerator()) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html `
            <style>
                .${name} {
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                    border: solid 2px red;
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 10px;
                    left: 450px;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="${name}">${name}</div>
        `);
    }
    main.addBad2Element = addBad2Element;
})(main || (main = {}));
// --
(function (main) {
    // --
    window.addEventListener('load', load.bind(main));
    // ---
    function load() {
        console.log('load');
        let conteiner = main.addConteiner(document.body);
        main.addButtons(conteiner);
        main.addBadElement(conteiner);
        main.addBad2Element(conteiner);
    }
})(main || (main = {}));
// <-- End
```